# Modal box in Laravel not appearing

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have a Laravel application. I can't get modal forms to work. I'm basing the code entirely on [this Bootsnipp example](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/clean-modal-login-form)

To test things out, I have defined a 'test' route, that loads the view 'test.blade.php'. The Blade code is as follows:

```
@extends('layout')

@section('content')

<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-modal">Login</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="login-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="loginmodal-container">
          <h1>Login to Your Account</h1><br>
          <form>
          <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username">
          <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
          <input type="submit" name="login" class="login loginmodal-submit" value="Login">
          </form>

          <div class="login-help">
          <a href="#">Register</a> - <a href="#">Forgot Password</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
@stop
```

I have a layout.blade.php file where I'm adding the css file from that example.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/homepage.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/table.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/modal.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I have put the modal.css file in the 'public/css' folder. When I view the page source it displays the css file which shows it loads correctly. Yet, the modal box is not appearing.

Comment: Did you include `jquery.js` and `bootstrap.js`?

Comment: Yes. I updated the question with how I included them. I just added the minimized version of Bootstrap and jQuery though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing your `layout.blade.php` I think that you've placed scripts in wrong order. `bootstrap.js` is depends to `jquery` so the order should be `jquery` in the first place:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This works indeed. Brilliant. Didn't think about that, but it's obvious!